# convert string to char with switch case

Tags: java

I am taking input from user in string and I want to iterate and test using case statement but it is not working. its not printing the statements.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class fh3

{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException

{

    String sentence = "";

    System.out.println("Enter the word : ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scan.next();


    char[] chars = word.toCharArray(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {

        System.out.println("---" + chars[i]);
        switch(chars[i])
        {
            case 0: sentence = " ";
                System.out.println("B");
                break;
            case 1: sentence = "A";
                break;
            case 2: sentence = "B";
                System.out.println("B");
                break;
            case 3: sentence = "C";
                break;


        }
        sentence+=sentence;
    System.out.println(sentence);
    }


}

}
```

if i enter 20 den it should print"B "
but its printing as

```
Enter the word :
20
---2

---0
```

where i am getting wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're doing the switch on `char` type, your case should have the same. In your case, since you give the case as integer values, its just not matching. **'0' is not equal to 0**

```
switch(chars[i]) {
    case '0': // switch on char '0' and not integer 0.
    case '1': // switch on char '1' and not integer 1.
    case '2': // switch on char '2' and not integer 2.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fh3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String sentence = "";
        System.out.println("Enter the word : ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = scan.next();

        //Switch case needs you to compare the expression with constants hence the final keyword. 
        final char CHARONE = '1';
        final char CHARTWO = '2';
        final char CHARTHREE = '3';
        final char CHARFOUR = '4';

        char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("---" + chars[i]);
            switch (chars[i]) {
                case 0:
                    sentence = " ";
                    System.out.println("B");
                    break;
                case CHARONE:
                    sentence = "A";
                    break;
                case CHARTWO:
                    sentence = "B";
                    System.out.println("B");
                    break;
                case CHARTHREE:
                    sentence = "C";
                    break;

            }
            sentence += sentence;
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }
    }
}
```

You were trying to compare int with char .. Clear ?

Comment: I guess you will need to correct case 0: too :-) . overlooked

Answer (score 1):

Because you're switching on **characters**, not integers :

```
switch(chars[i]){
    case '0': sentence = " ";
           System.out.println("B");
           break;
    case '1': sentence = "A";
           break;
    case '2': sentence = "B";
           System.out.println("B");
           break;
     case '3': sentence = "C";
           break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your switch is accepting `char` but no suitable `case` is there.So its printing only this statement `System.out.println("---" + chars[i]);` two times(because `word.length()` returns 2 in your case)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class fh3

{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException

{

    String sentence = "";

    System.out.println("Enter the word : ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scan.next();


    char[] chars = word.toCharArray(); 

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {

        System.out.println("---" + chars[i]);
        switch(chars[i])
        {
            case '0': sentence = " ";
                System.out.println("B");
                break;
            case '1': sentence = "A";
                break;
            case '2': sentence = "B";
                System.out.println("B");
                break;
            case '3': sentence = "C";
                break;


        }
        sentence+=sentence;
    System.out.println(sentence);
    }


}

}
```

Comment: How can it work, as his characters contains alphabets and not numbers

Comment: @Prateek yes thats why cases are of char type

Comment: No thats why fine but the value of cases is'0','1' etc. i m talking in context to his program, i m not saying your code is wrong.

Comment: @Prateek see others answers too,they are similar to my type.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `char` type maps to the `int` type via the [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Therefore, if you want to check the char `'0'` and not the `NUL` char, you should do:

```
switch(chars[i]) {
    case '0': // do the work
    case '1': // do the work
    // ...
}
```